# How travel tracking/travel blog apps make money?

Tags: tracking

My question seems to be weird here but I cannot find any answers for my questions on the Internet.

There are two top travel tracking/travel blog apps right now. They seem to offer members free services. I am wondering how they make money to maintain their businesses.

Comment: Questions here are required to be about a [website under your own control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to avoid speculative and opinion-based answers.